# Why are space probes / satellites data rates so low?

Tags: communication, new-horizons, deep-space, data-transmission, radio-communication

The New Horizon's data transfer rate is only about 2kbps right now. At its peak the rate was 38kbps. Why is this transfer rate so slow? Is this due to using radio waves, limitations in the data relay, Doppler effect, etc?

Comment: See [Why does data transfer rate decrease with distance](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/7776/49)

Comment: Downvoted )+: Sorry. 
Almost a duplicate seeing that there are several similar questions in the context of low data rates amongst deep-space craft

Comment: That's fine, did a search and could not find it so I asked. Thanks.