# What is the modulation technique and what is the coding technique used to send information from the New Horizons spacecraft?

Tags: communication, new-horizons

I would like to know what is the modulation technique used on the New Horizons Spacecraft? Is it BPSK or GMSK?
Also what is the coding technique-turbo-codes or LDPC codes?
And do you have a link budget available?

Comment: 2 of your 3 questions are answered here: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/7776/why-does-data-transfer-rate-decrease-with-distance

Comment: @Hobbes - the linked question does not **directly** deal with modulation, I'd be loath to close this one as a dupe. It is too broad, though.

Comment: Irving, please choose one specific question instead of three, bearing in mind the link posted by @Hobbes.

Comment: @Deer Hunter: Phil Karn's answer to that question contains the data Irving's looking for (BPSK and turbo-coding).

Answer (score 3):

Phil has explained it nicely. Yes, it is BPSK with R=1/6 Turbo coding, that is used in New Horizons. Some aspects of the X band digital receiver used is discussed [here](http://www.boulder.swri.edu/~tcase/NH%20Uplink%20Card%20Paper_Haskins.pdf). For the coding enthusiasts, I can add that the Blocklength is k=1784 bits (even though it is programmable, for low data rate support, this minimum block length is used). The information code length (post coding) n =(k+4)/R=10728 bits.

Comment: Welcome to Space.SE. This is a very interesting information. However it covers the uplink receiver, not the downlink transmitter which is the topic in the question. Any chance you can get a similar paper?

Comment: The turbo coding is in fact for the downlink.  The uplink is not coded.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought Phil had mentioned the DL reference circuit [link](http://www.boulder.swri.edu/~tcase/NH%20RF%20Telecom%20Sys%20ID1369%20FINAL_Deboy.pdf) already. Yes I was referring to the DL (Turbo coding). That is where the most critical/precious data (e.g., image data) is coming. Also, the most sophisticated of the receivers (turbo decoder, synchronization to name a few) can be implemented in the ground than in the space station.