# How can the download speed increase from space probes?

Tags: planet, velocity, space-probe, raw-data

It always seems to be a genuine question that is **How can we download data from far away probes in instant**. When New Horizons reached Ultima Thule, it took us quite a few months to have a great picture of the same though we predicted and analysed the Celestial body before the complete data being available. I know it takes few hours for data to be transferred from either side (even at the speed of light) but data download speed is in bits ( had read somewhere on the internet). How can we increase the download speed to a very great extent. As in Megabytes, Terabytes, etc. 
1) Will Installing space probes and cube satellites around planets, comets and asteroids help?
 2) What are the options available? 
3) What would be the expenditure and feasibility?

Comment: See https://scienceandtechnology.jpl.nasa.gov/research/research-topics-list/communications-computing-software/deep-space-communications

Comment: You did ask this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41344/how-can-the-download-speed-increase-from-space-probes) before and got an answer, so you should delete this copy.